# MySQL Find which condition is satisfied in if

Tags: mysql, sql

Okay.. this might look weird but is there any way to find which condition was satisfied among multiple conditions in a if statement? I'm writing a Trigger in MySql 5.1, and i have to raise an error on certain condition.
I want to do something like code below,

```
if(new.col1 = 'A' and (new.col2 is null or new.col3 is null) {
    //if new.col1 = 'A' and **new.col2** was null
    set msg = '<col2> cannot be null';
}
if(new.col1 = 'B' and (new.col4 is null or new.col5 is null) {
    //if new.col1 = 'B'and **new.col5** was null
    set msg = '<col5> cannot be null';
}
```

If I get any solution to this, then i will be saving 1000s `if` loops!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SIGNAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/signal.html) statement to raise an error -

```
IF NEW.col1 = 'A' AND (NEW.col2 IS NULL OR new.col3 IS NULL) THEN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '20001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'col2 cannot be null';
ELSEIF NEW.col1 = 'B' AND (NEW.col4 IS NULL OR new.col5 IS NULL) THEN
  SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '20001' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'col5 cannot be null';
END IF;
```

The SIGNAL command is available in MySQL 5.5 and higher.

As you use MySQL 5.1, you can use a workaround -

```
IF NEW.col1 = 'A' AND (NEW.col2 IS NULL OR new.col3 IS NULL) THEN
  CALL `col2 cannot be null()`;
ELSEIF NEW.col1 = 'B' AND (NEW.col4 IS NULL OR new.col5 IS NULL) THEN
  CALL `col5 cannot be null()`;
END IF
```

In this case the error message won't as expected, but the code will be interrupted and error will be raised.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. But raising an error is not my problem. I have used CALL to it. But See the error message, I want to construct an error message depending on what condition was satisfied in if statement. If col2 was null then my message would be 'col2 cannot be null' if col3 was null then 'col3 cannot be null' 
I have edited my question a little bit.

Comment: Hmm, I see. Seems it cannot be automated.

Comment: Can not you use NOT NULL option in column definition? It could help you to constraint inserting NULL values.

Comment: No!! There is single table for an entity of different types. As per the framework, if I create and entity of type 'A' then entity type 'B' related columns are allowed to be null. I searched for "check constraint", but it didn't work for me. Finally i ended up in the trigger.

Comment: Check constraint are not supported in MySQL, and it is sad;) You can use triggers, you can use procedures to check values and to insert, but error messages should be written manually.